# FLUTTER /encrypt getting 32o string when encrypting 16o String with NO PADDING

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes

i have a problem with my AES128-cbc with no padding, when I give it a 16o String it give me back a 32o String (I have no padding)

Could you help me understand what's going on ?
Thank you very much ^^

PS : I use the Encrypt library : https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt

**Here is a part of my Encrypter class**

```
class AESEncryptor{
      var iv;
      var encrypter;
      var key;
    
      AESEncryptor(){
        this.key = Key.fromSecureRandom(16);
        this.iv = IV.fromLength(16);
        this.encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: null));
      }
    
      void setIV(iv){
        this.iv=iv;
      }
    
      IV getIv(){
        return(this.iv);
      }
    
      void setKey(key){
        this.key=key;
      }
    
      Key getKey(){
        return(this.key);
      }
    
      dynamic encrypt(data){ 
        if (data.runtimeType==Key){
          data=data.base16;
    
        }
        return encrypter.encrypt(data, iv: this.iv);
      }
    }
```

Comment: The ciphertext should include the IV, or it will be impossible to decrypt.

Comment: AES/CBC isn't supposed to create word of the initial size ? When I do the same thing in Kotlin with javax.crypto it works perfectly

Comment: In the line `data=data.base16` the data is hex encoded, i.e. each byte is represented by two hex digits, which doubles the length of the data (so that e.g. 16 bytes become 32 bytes).

Comment: Yes it is, but the format is this one so it is not supposed to cause any problem [0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF] (16words of 1o)
EDIT : Sorry I think you're right I will test that and update

Comment: Just debug the code. E.g. if the key to encrypt is created with `var keyToEnc = enc.Key.fromUtf8('0123456789012345')`, it is 16 bytes. Then, the line `data=data.base16` returns the string `30313233343536373839303132333435`. Finally, `encrypt()` performs a Utf8 encoding prior to encryption, so 32 bytes are created, resulting in a 32 bytes ciphertext without padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Topaco I found out how to correct it

**New code**

```
 dynamic encrypt(data){ 
    if (data.runtimeType==Key){
      data=toInt(combineByTwo(data.base16.split('')));
    }
    return encrypter.encryptBytes(data, iv: this.iv);
  }
```

**The two (dirty for the moment) functions I use :**

```
List<int> toInt(chaine){
  List<int> tab=[];
  for (var i=0;i<chaine.length;i++){
    tab.add(int.parse(chaine[i],radix:16));
  }
  return tab;
}

List combineByTwo(list){ 
  List tab=[];
  for (var i=0;i<list.length;i+=2){
    tab.add(list[i]+list[i+1]);
  }
  return tab;
}
```